# bcrypt compare not matching any passwords at login

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, postman, bcrypt

I have a pretty odd issue. I'm building authentication features for a web app; registration, login. This is using mongodb and bcrypt. Everything was working as expected; in Postman I could register a new user, log them in, and access public and auth only routes (logged out, logged in, respectively) to ensure it was working as expected. I had to move everything to a different directory and also a different code repo, and since then it seems `bcrypt.compare()` is failing every time I try to log in, even though I can confirm the user is successfully added to the DB. I have run the relevant files through a diff checker to see if anything has changed and am unable to identify any major differences, hoping someone might have some insight. Including the register and login routes, as well as the user model below; if more context is needed I'll add more.

**Register route**

```
app.post('/register', (request, response) => {
  bcrypt.hash(request.body.password, 10)
    .then((hashedPassword) => {
      const user = new User({
        email: request.body.email,
        password: hashedPassword,
      });

      user
        .save()
        .then((result) => {
          response.status(201).send({
            message: 'User created successfully',
            result,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          response.status(500).send({
            message: 'Error creating user',
            error,
          });
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      response.status(500).send({
        message: 'Password was not hashed successfully',
        error,
      });
    });
});
```

**Login route**

```
app.post('/login', (request, response) => {
  User.findOne({ email: request.body.email })
    .then((user) => {
      bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, user.password)
        .then((passwordCheck) => {
          if (!passwordCheck) {
            return response.status(400).send({
              message: 'Password does not match',
              error,
            });
          }

          const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              userId: user._id,
              userEmail: user.email,
            },
            'RANDOM-TOKEN',
            { expiresIn: '24h' }
          );

          response.status(200),send({
            message: 'Login Successful',
            email: user.email,
            token,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          response.status(400).send({
            message: 'Password does not match',
            error,
          });
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      response.status(404).send({
        message: 'User not found',
        error,
      });
    });
});
```

**User Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please provide an Email!"],
    unique: [true, "Email Exists"],
  },

  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please provide a password!"],
    unique: false,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model.Users || mongoose.model("Users", UserSchema);
```

**Postman tabs/results, Mongo entry**
[image: successful registration]

[image: unsuccessful login]

[image: mongo collection entry]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a salt issue, since you said that you changed the repository, I think bcrypt is not able to get the same salt and hence it is failing. Check if you have configured that properly.